# Regular expression Matching

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to search a document for a matching string (a place holder) and I am struggling to get the regular expression right.

The string I am trying to find will be in this format, it can be found anywhere in the document

> ##MYPH[j@_-jdf]##

The regular expression I am trying to use is:

```
##MYPH\[([-!$%@^&*()_+|~=`{}:";'<>?,.\/]+(\w)+(\W)+)\]##
```

The `##MYPH[]##` will always be the same but the text between the square brackets could be anything.
Eventually I will just need to return what's in the square brackets.

I have been testing this but I am not getting a match.

I have switched out the `+` for a `*` and then I get a match but there doesn't have to be anything in the brackets.
I have also tried removing the `*` and `+` completely and still no match.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Haven't you tried [`##MYPH\[(.*?)]##`](https://regex101.com/r/nM6fA7/1)?

Comment: Missing the obvious! ##MPPH\[.+?\]## works! (with the +) If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.  Bonus points if you can tell me how to get the text between the square brackets.

Comment: What is the regex flavor/language? Then I can post an answer. Or at least understand whether to post or not.

Comment: I am coding in c#but have just been testing using this: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Wrong tool for testing .NET regexps.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Haven't you checked the options at regex101? Only PCRE, JS and Python. Try `[\w-[\d]]` there. It won't work. Use regexstorm.net or regexhero.net, and if you need explanations, use Ultrapico Expresso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
##MYPH\[(.*?)]##
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%23MYPH%5C%5B(.*%3F)%5D%23%23&i=%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23). This regex is good for short strings. For longer ones, use its unrolled equivalent `##MYPH\[([^]]*(?:](?!##)[^]]*)*)]##` (see [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23%23MYPH%5C%5B(%5B%5E%5D%5D*(%3F%3A%5D(%3F!%23%23)%5B%5E%5D%5D*)*)%5D%23%23&i=%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23%23%23MYPH%5Bj%40_-jdf%5D%23%23)).

**Pattern explanation**:

- `##MYPH\[` -  a literal `##MYPH[`
- `(.*?)` - (Capture group 1) any 0+ characters but a newline (add `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to match a newline, too) up to the first
- `]##` - a literal string `]##`

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/UWvjoL):

```
var line = "##MYPH[j@_-jdf]##";
var pattern = @"##MYPH\[(.*?)]##";
var m = Regex.Match(line, pattern);
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

Or a [C# demo for multiple matches](http://ideone.com/tEPuIH):

```
var line = "##MYPH[1j@_-jdf]####MYPH[2j@_-jdf]####MYPH[3j@_-jdf]####MYPH[4j@_-jdf]####MYPH[5j@_-jdf]##";
var pattern = @"##MYPH\[(.*?)]##";
var m = Regex.Matches(line, pattern)
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
        .ToList();
foreach (var s in m)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one:

```
##MYPH\[[\S]+\]##
```

Comment: Note that `[\S]+` = `\S+`

Comment: According to the question the part between the [ and ] could be anything. This regular expression would not find white space characters. It also wouldn't match if the part between the [ and ] was empty. Also if there were two such strings to be found next to each other it would only match once thinking the end of the second was actually the end of the first.